# Bug in Groovy withBatch (or maybe JDBC driver)?

Tags: sql, jdbc, groovy, sybase, jtds

I have a following update code:

```
String updateSqlText = "update myTable set id=1006, floatParam=? where sud_id=10067237";

def updateCounts = sql.withBatch(1, updateSqlText) { ps ->
    def args = [null]
    ps.addBatch(args)
}
```

when I run it it tells me: 
Caught: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Implicit conversion from datatype VARCHAR' to 'FLOAT' is not allowed.  Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

However if I do this:

```
String updateSqlText = "update myTable set id=1006, floatParam=? where sud_id=10067237";
def args = [null]
imagineSql.executeUpdate(updateSqlText, args)
```

it works without problem

The parameter is a float and it looks like it tries to convert null to string when I call withBatch but works fine with regular update.

I am using Sybase and jTDS jdbc driver.

Edit: Looks like if I change

```
def args = [null]
```

to

```
def args = [Types.NULL]
```

that it works. I guess Groovy needs to be modified to do just that in withBatch.

Edit2: Now I am facing a problem adding null to Varchar - it gives me

> Caught: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Implicit conversion from
>   datatype 'INT' to 'VARCHAR' is not allowed.  Use the CONVERT function
>   to run this query.

Comment: Have you tried doing this from Java? This Groovy API hides a lot of the API of JDBC, so it is likely doing some tricks on the background that might break. If you can (or know how) to break it directly from Java, it is easier to tell if it is a JDBC driver bug or a Groovy problem.

Comment: I am trying to go the easy route first :) This is just a simplified example of what I do to show the specific problem. I have a bunch of dynamic parameters that I put in update and they are getting updated from a select I do from different database, so I am trying to keep it simple since there is already enough complexity. I would prefer if I didn't need to specify the parameter types if possible.

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd think that either Groovy uses `PreparedStatement.setObject(int, Object)` and the jTDS driver defaults to `Types.VARCHAR` for `null`, or Groovy uses `setString(int, String)` for `null`).

Comment: But it somehow works for executeUpdate(updateSqlText, args). What would be the solution here? I have millions of updates and without batch it doesn't really work, takes too much time.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try specifying the bind var as a NullObject ?

```
sql.withBatch(1, updateSqlText) {
   def args = [org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.getNullObject()]
}
```

or possibly

```
Float myFloatArg = null;  // or = 23.4f;
sql.withBatch(1, updateSqlText) {
   def args = [myFloatArg]
}
```

Comment: the first parameter in withBatch is the number of batched statements, I made it 1 to make the example simple. The parameter I add is in     def args = [null], so I am adding null that will go into float field.

Comment: Sorry, I did not read this through carefully enough. Updated answer.

Comment: got this: java.sql.SQLException: Unable to convert between org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject and JAVA_OBJECT.

Comment: I tried Types.NULL and that worked. So I guess I would need to substitute nulls with this. Would have been nicer if it was done automatically in Groovy.

Comment: Ok, tried this on my code that has different types and this doesn't work when I try to put null to Varchar - Implicit conversion from datatype 'INT' to 'VARCHAR' is not allowed.